# How to encrypt sns topic at rest to avoid cloud alters

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, ansible, devops, amazon-sns

Currently sns topics are getting generated from an ansible script, below is the snippet where I think it is getting generated.

```
    Resources:
     NotificaionTopic:
        Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
        Properties:
          Subscription:
           - Endpoint: xxxx@test.com
             protocol: email
```

I need to encrypt the sns topics, can you please let me what changes I need to make so that it will start  encrypting sns topics.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a `KmsMasterKeyId` to the resource, the service will encrypt the topic.

```
Type: AWS::SNS::Topic
Properties: 
  ContentBasedDeduplication: Boolean
  DisplayName: String
  KmsMasterKeyId: String
  Subscription: 
    - Subscription
  Tags: 
    - Tag
  TopicName: String
```

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html